# Making geolocation coordinates available to other functions

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm working on a basic JavaScript weather application. I'd like to pull the geolocation from the browser and make it accessible to my other functions.

```
function Weather( options ) {

    this.apiKey = options.key;
    this.endpoint = options.endpoint;
    this.coordinates = {};
}

Weather.prototype.GetLocation = function( callback ) {
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function(position) {
            this.coordinates.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            this.coordinates.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        });
    }
};

Weather.prototype.GetCurrentConditions = function() {

    this.GetLocation();

    var url = this.endpoint + "weather?lat=" + this.coordinates.latitude + "&lon=" + this.coordinates.longitude;

    return this.getJSONP( url );
};

Weather.prototype.GetExtendedForecast = function() {

    this.GetLocation();

    var url = this.endpoint + "forecast/daily?lat=" + this.coordinates.latitude + "&lon=" + this.coordinates.longitude + "&cnt=7";

    return this.getJSONP( url );
};
```

However, I keep getting undefined as my latitude and longitude. I read somewhere that if you want to use the coordinates that you have to save them in the callback function of getCurrentPosition which is what I did but I'm still unable to get anything other than undefined. Is there a way to make these values accessible to my other functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Firstly**, `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback works asynchronously, so you won't get results right after calling `this.GetLocation()`. Also, user can forbid to share his location with an application.

**Secondly**, you have a mistake with `this`. You need to pass context to callback here:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function(position) {
    // "this" doesn't equal to instance of your Weather class
    this.coordinates.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.coordinates.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
});
```

For example, you can use `.bind(this)` to pass expected context to callback:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function(position) {
    this.coordinates.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.coordinates.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}.bind(this));
```

**My solution**

It's better to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for async code. You can use any implementation of Promise, I prefer [JQuery.deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

My code is:

```
var getCurrentPosition = function() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
  } else {
    deferred.reject({
      error: 'browser doesn\'t support geolocation'
    });
  }

  return deferred.promise();
};
```

**How to use it**

```
var userPositionPromise = getCurrentPosition();

userPositionPromise
  .then(function(data) {
    // do whatever you want with geolocation data
  })
  .fail(function(error) {
    // show error for user
  });
```

You can use `userPositionPromise` as long as you want, it will be as container for user position data, you don't need to call `getUserPosition` again. To access to data, you need to call `.then(callback)` for your  `userPositionPromise` variable.

Comment: How would you go about doing the binding without jQuery? I'm trying to get better at using pure JavaScript in my projects.

Comment: You can write this without jQuery using native [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), it will look like same, but it [doesn't work on IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=Promise) (so, you need to use [polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)). Or you can write this without Promise, but you need to use a lot of callbacks and flags to check data.

Comment: In your jsfiddle I see that you have a reject but where are you resolving the coordinates?

Comment: I call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and pass two callbacks: `resolve` and `reject`. When `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` successfully executed, it calls `resolve` callback, that resolves my promise with data. So, I just passing `resolve` from promise to `getCurrentPosition` as onSuccess callback. You can write it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1r1bdmrb/1/ but first version looks more clean.

Comment: Ok here's what I have at the moment. https://jsfiddle.net/08yrdact/
However, I'm getting an error saying that fail is not a function. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using nativa promise, you need to use `catch`. `fail` - is jquery deferred method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104944/discussion-between-timur-bilalov-and-randomlyknighted).